# Strange results with Carbon filter on Eloquent collection in blade template

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade, php-carbon

I have a weird issue that I can't see any obvious solution to.

I am building a jQuery graph of transaction totals for the last 30 days but I am not getting the proper output. Here is the relevant blade template code:

```
@for ($i = 29; $i >= 1; $i--)
{y: '{{ \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDays($i)->toDateString() }}', item1: '{{ $transactions->whereDate('created_at', '=', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDays($i)->toDateString())->where('status', 'C')->sum('amount') }}'},  
@endfor
{y: '{{ \Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateString() }}', item1: '{{ $transactions->where('created_at', '>=', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateString())->where('status', 'C')->sum('amount') }}'}
```

With my dummy data, when $i=3 it should return '10.00' and everything else should return '0'.

Couple notes: If I make the FIRST output as '3 days ago', it returns the expected value. Example:

```
{y: '{{ \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDays(3)->toDateString() }}', item1: '{{ $transactions->whereDate('created_at', '=', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDays(3)->toDateString())->where('status', 'C')->sum('amount') }}'},
@for ($i = 29; $i >= 1; $i--)
{y: '{{ \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDays($i)->toDateString() }}', item1: '{{ $transactions->whereDate('created_at', '=', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDays($i)->toDateString())->where('status', 'C')->sum('amount') }}'},  
@endfor
{y: '{{ \Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateString() }}', item1: '{{ $transactions->where('created_at', '>=', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateString())->where('status', 'C')->sum('amount') }}'}
```

Also, if I hard code any values into the graph it works fine so that *should* rule out any jQuery issue. So in essence it seems that only the first time I use this call it works.

I'm assuming the solution is to clean up the amount of Carbon/collection calls (since there is like 60 total), but I'm not quite sure where to start on that. I am passing a collection from my controller as 'transactions'.

Result:

```
{y: '2016-06-18', item1: '0'},
...
{y: '2016-07-15', item1: '0'},
{y: '2016-07-16', item1: '0'},
{y: '2016-07-17', item1: '0'},
{y: '2016-07-18', item1: '0'}
```

Expected result:

```
{y: '2016-06-18', item1: '0'},
...
{y: '2016-07-15', item1: '10.00'},
{y: '2016-07-16', item1: '0'},
{y: '2016-07-17', item1: '0'},
{y: '2016-07-18', item1: '0'}
```

Answer (score 0):

try doing

```
with(clone $transaction)->query_here
```

your query might be overwritten/changed through out the loop.

Hope it helped!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have some logic error. Anyway, you shouldn't build the graph data in your view. Instead place the logic in your controller, or better yet in a presenter or service class. However for now, placing it in your controller will be just fine.

Try this, in your controller, add:

```
$graph = [];
$currentDay = \Carbon\Carbon::now();

for ($i=0; $i < 30; $i++) {
    if ($i > 0) {
        // Subtract a day starting from the second loop
        $currentDay->subDay();
    }

    $dateString = $currentDay->toDateString();

    $currentDayData = [
        'y' => $dateString,
        'item1' => $transactions->whereDate('created_at', $dateString)->where('status', 'C')->sum('amount'),
    ];

    // Prepend to final array
    array_unshift($graph, $currentDayData);
}

$graph = json_encode($graph);

// Don't forget to export $graph to your view
```

Then in your view place the JSON string in the appropriate `data-*` attribute. For example:

```
<div id="graph" data-graph="{{ $graph }}"></div>
```

Finally in your `.js` file you can grab the data and build the graph from there:

```
// Note: You don't need to parse the JSON string manually
// since jquery will do that automatically in this case
const data = $('#graph').data('graph');

// Then feed the data into whatever graph API that you use
```

**I haven't tested this code**, so let me know how it goes.